# Help in solving an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Could someone help to solve this integral?

$\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }{{{({{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}+{{z}^{2}})}^{-\tfrac{3}{2}}}\cdot \left( {{\left( 1-\frac{{{(x\cdot u+y\cdot v-z\cdot w)}^{2}}}{{{c}^{2}}\cdot ({{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}+{{z}^{2}})} \right)}^{-\tfrac{1}{2}}}-{{\left( 1-\frac{{{(x\cdot u+y\cdot v-z\cdot (w+d))}^{2}}}{{{c}^{2}}\cdot ({{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}+{{z}^{2}})} \right)}^{-\tfrac{1}{2}}} \right)dz}$

All parameters and the variable *z* are real. The parameter *d* is real and positive. All parameters are independent of *z*.
I am not sure it can be solved. However, it is possible to solve the simplified version obtained by making *u*=*v*=0. Namely,

$\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }{{{({{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}+{{z}^{2}})}^{-\tfrac{3}{2}}}\cdot \left( {{\left( 1-\frac{{{(-z\cdot w)}^{2}}}{{{c}^{2}}\cdot ({{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}+{{z}^{2}})} \right)}^{-\tfrac{1}{2}}}-{{\left( 1-\frac{{{(-z\cdot (w+d))}^{2}}}{{{c}^{2}}\cdot ({{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}+{{z}^{2}})} \right)}^{-\tfrac{1}{2}}} \right)dz}=$
$\frac{2c\left( (d+w)\arcsin \left( \frac{w}{c} \right)-w\arcsin \left( \frac{d+w}{c} \right) \right)}{w(d+w)({{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}})}$

Many thanks

Comment: where did you get this question from ?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }{{{(a^2+{{z}^{2}})}^{-\tfrac{3}{2}}}\cdot \left( {{\left( 1-\frac{{{(b-z\cdot w)}^{2}}}{{{c}^{2}}\cdot (a^2+{{z}^{2}})} \right)}^{-\tfrac{1}{2}}}-{{\left( 1-\frac{{{(b-z\cdot (w+d))}^{2}}}{{{c}^{2}}\cdot (a^2+{{z}^{2}})} \right)}^{-\tfrac{1}{2}}} \right)dz}$ is easier to look at

Comment: This is a good idea, Paul 5 !